# I have a problem with srt source multiaudio output

Tags: gstreamer, decklink

Hallo i have a problem with gstreamer srt source multiaudio output on decklink card.when i switch the channes on sdi monitor ther is only one audio.`GST_DEBUG=3 gst-launch-1.0 -v srtsrc uri=srt://xxxxxx:xxxx latency=200 !\ tsdemux name=demux demux. ! h264parse ! video/x-h264 ! avdec_h264 !\ queue ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=UYVY !\ decklinkvideosink mode=1080i50 sync=false demux. ! avdec_aac ! queue !\ audioconvert ! audio/x-raw, format=S16LE, channels=2 ! decklinkaudiosink`